# How to convince Flink to rename .inprogress files to part-xxx

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We have unit tests for a  streaming workflow (using Flink 1.14.4) with bounded sources, writing Parquet files. Because it's bounded, checkpointing is automatically disabled (as per the INFO msg `Disabled Checkpointing. Checkpointing is not supported and not needed when executing jobs in BATCH mode.`), which means setting `ExecutionCheckpointingOptions.ENABLE_CHECKPOINTS_AFTER_TASKS_FINISH` to true has no effect.

Is the only solution to run the harness with unbounded sources in a separate thread, and force it to terminate when no more data is written to the output? Seems awkward...

Comment: Are you sure that `execution.checkpointing.checkpoints-after-tasks-finish.enabled` is irrelevant?

Comment: I thought that with bounded sources executing in BATCH mode that the files would automatically be finalized. I take it that's not the case?

Comment: Hi David - I set `execution.checkpointing.checkpoints-after-tasks-finish.enabled` to true, and it didn't change the behavior. But maybe there's something else going on that I need to resolve.

Comment: Are you using the FileSink (and not the StreamingFileSink)?

Comment: It's like you were reading my code :) Yes, we hadn't finished converting all of our sinks to the new FileSink; once we updated it then we got the expected results.

Answer (score 2):

The solution, for others, is:

1. Make sure you're using `FileSink`, not the older `StreamingFileSink`.
2. Set `ExecutionCheckpointingOptions.ENABLE_CHECKPOINTS_AFTER_TASKS_FINISH` to true.

Comment: This worked for me too, I also enabled periodic checkpointing, something like:

`env.enableCheckpointing(15000)`